# Windows 10 getting stuck while working on any of its application

Tags: windows-10

After I installed windows 10 on my machine I am facing a big problem operating the computer.

Problem : It gets stuck every few seconds.e.g while typing a message I have to wait to notice when the cursor will start/stop blinking so I can start/stop typing. I am really getting frustrated. Any ideas how do I revertback to win7 or apply a patch for this bug.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well same happened to me but after hiding Cortana "Ask me anything" box the trouble gone. To do this TaskBar==>right click==> Cortana==> hidden. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Cortana is not supported in your region it says. I removed the search box from the taskbar and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I am happy this worked for you.